# Understand vmstat output in Solaris

Tags: linux, performance, cpu-usage, solaris

What does r b w column exactly means in vmstat output.

Does r means number of threads which are waiting for CPU or number of threads currently running .

Also what does b and w column means.

When i run vmstat on our system we get values in r column as more than 20 , 30 sometimes . Is this an issue . Does it mean 20 , 30 threads are waiting for CPU and  do we need to increase CPU in that scenario.

Also if someone can point to any documentation which explain this in detail .

Answer (score 0):

They are processes not threads:

From 'man vmstat':
     The fields of vmstat's display are

```
      procs Report the number of processes  in  each  of  the
            three following states:

            r     in run queue

            b     blocked for resources I/O, paging,  and  so
                  forth

            w     swapped
```

Comment: This is what i got for vmstat in solaris --------------



                 r    the number of kernel threads in run queue --------------

                 b    the number of blocked kernel threads  that  are  waiting
                      for resources I/O, paging, and so forth -----------------

                 w    the  number  of swapped out lightweight processes (LWPs)
                      that are waiting for processing resources to finish.

Comment: your man page is probably correct as I have an old version of Solaris.